# Java, Using Scanner to input characters as UTF-8, can't print text

Tags: java

I can convert String to Array as UTF-8, but I can't convert it back to String like the first String.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner h = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("INPUT : ");
    String stringToConvert = h.nextLine();
    byte[] theByteArray = stringToConvert.getBytes();

    System.out.println(theByteArray);
    theByteArray.toString();
    String s = new String(theByteArray);

    System.out.println(""+s);
}
```

How do I print `theByteArray` as a String?

Comment: Looks like it's working fine to me: http://ideone.com/rcvXl

Comment: Provide test input / expected output / actual output.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
String s = new String(theByteArray);
```

should really be

```
String s = new String(theByteArray, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

The underlying issue here is that String constructors aren't smart.  The String constructor cannot distinguish the charset that is being used and will try to convert it using the system standard which is generally something like ASCII or ISO-8859-1.  This is why normal A-Za-z looks proper but then everything else begins to fail.

byte is a type that runs from -127 to 127 thus for UTF-8 conversion consecutive bytes need to be concatenated.  It's impossible for the String constructor to distinguish this off a byte array so it will handle each byte individually by default (thus why basic alphanumeric will always work as they fall into this range).

Example:

```
String text = "こんにちは";
byte[] array = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
String s = new String(array, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
System.out.println(s); // Prints as expected
String sISO = new String(array, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")); // Prints 'ããã«ã¡ã¯'
System.out.println(sISO);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with the provided code:

1. You are not ensuring that you are getting the UTF-8 byte array from that String.

   ```
   byte[] theByteArray = stringToConvert.getBytes();
   ```

   returns a byte array with the default encoding on the given platform, as described by the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29). What you actually want to do is the following:

   ```
   byte[] theByteArray = stringToConvert.getBytes("UTF-8");
   ```
2. You should check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) for `System.out.println()`:

   ```
   System.out.println(theByteArray);
   ```

   is calling `System.out.println(Object x)`, which will print the results of `x.toString()`. By default, toString() returns the memory address of the given object.

   So when you see output of the form:

   > INPUT :
   >
   > [B@5f1121f6
   >
   > inputText

   What you are seeing is the memory location of theByteArray and then the given input line of text.
3. You seem to not understand the 'x.toString()' method. Remember, Strings in Java are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object); None of String's methods will alter the String. `theByteArray.toString();` **returns** a string representation of `theByteArray;`. The returned value is thrown out unless you give the value to another String

   ```
   String arrayAsString = theByteArray.toString();
   ```

   However, as previously described, the returned String will be the memory location of `theByteArray`. In order to print out the contents of `theByteArray`, you will need to convert it to a String

   ```
   String convertedString = new String(theByteArray, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
   ```

**Assuming** your requirements are to print the converted String and then print the original String, your code should look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner h = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("INPUT : ");
    String stringToConvert = h.nextLine();

    try {
        // Array of the UTF-8 representation of the given String
        byte[] theByteArray;
        theByteArray = stringToConvert.getBytes("UTF-8");

        // The converted String
        System.out.println(new String(theByteArray, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // We may provide an invalid character set
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // The original String
    System.out.println(stringToConvert);
}
```