# Java Robot class press Turkish letter (Ö, ö, Ş, ş, Ü, ü, Ğ, ğ, İ, ı, Ç, ç, Ə, ə)?

Tags: java, class, keycode, awtrobot

I have problem with press a special letter (Turkish etc.) via java robot class. I hava a method to press keys which works as alt+keycode. I cant convert some special letters to current keycode. So how can I solve it. Thanx

For Example:

```
KeyStroke ks = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('ö', 0);
 System.out.println(ks.getKeyCode());
 Output : 246
 // So alt+0246='ö'
 //but if I convert 'ş' to keycode
 //Output is 351 . So alt+351= '_' and alt+0351= '_' 
 //What is the Correct combination for 'ş'. same for 'Ş', 'ş','Ğ', 'ğ', 'İ', 'ı', 'Ə', 'ə'
```

KeyPress:

```
public void altNumpad(int... numpadCodes) {
    if (numpadCodes.length == 0) {
        return;
    }

    robot.keyPress(VK_ALT);

    for (int NUMPAD_KEY : numpadCodes) {
        robot.keyPress(NUMPAD_KEY);
        robot.keyRelease(NUMPAD_KEY);
    }

    robot.keyRelease(VK_ALT);
}
```

Comment: Are some of these characters outside the BMP?

Comment: From [this link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/015f/index.htm), it appears that under Windows you should use Alt+015F. I don't have Windows so I can't test...

Comment: doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: you can't press Alt+015F in Windows unless you have enabled `EnableHexNumpad` in registry http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code

Comment: without HexNumpad only codepoints 1-255 can be entered

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make the Java.awt.Robot type unicode characters? (Is it possible?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397113/how-to-make-the-java-awt-robot-type-unicode-characters-is-it-possible)

Comment: Thanks for all, but I tested doesn't work, it may be necessary to use another class than class Robot

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279773/can-we-insert-unicode-characters-using-robot-class-in-java

Comment: Did you try pressing the keys exactly like in the above links (`Alt`-`+HEX`)? Make sure to press `+` before the hexadecimal codepoint value, unlike decimal version

Comment: Yes, I tested pressUnicode(new Robot(), 0x15F); it gives me the same result of my previous program output : _

Comment: @user3210664 as I said, on Windows you must enable HexNumpad in registry, then press `Alt`+`+CODE`. That function simply presses decimal code, so it won't work in Windows

Answer (score 2):

The character numbers are defiunied in the Unicode standard. The are also used in HTML, therefore you can use [this table](http://character-code.com/turkish-html-codes.php).

Anyway if you see the character in the source code depends on the fact that the editor interprets the file correctly (UTF-8 is preferred).

Second the used editor must have a font installed that contains these characters. Hence if you type alt+0351 and get and '_' this may just be a replacement character indicating that the font misses this character.

And in the end you should tell the Java compiler that the source code is UTF-8 - just to make sure (`javac -encoding utf8`).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you did

```
KeyStroke ks = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('ö', 0);
```

Because java docs say,

```
public static KeyStroke getKeyStroke(Character keyChar,
                 int modifiers)
//Use 0 to specify no modifiers.
```

you need to pass a modifier other than 0 to the overload.

You should try to pass a modification like,

```
java.awt.event.InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK
```

So probably should try,

```
KeyStroke ks = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('ö', java.awt.event.InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK);
```

Java doc as reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke(char)

If you cannot properly get a output from that then you should consider the fact the character is UTF-8 
This might help you in that regard, [Java, Using Scanner to input characters as UTF-8, can't print text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980699/why-i-can-not-print-anythings-text-with-utf-8-when-use-scanner-to-input)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer but here it is how I handle this problem for Turkish QWERTY keyboard

```
   static void writeRobotWrite(Robot robot, String keys) throws InterruptedException {
    ....
        try {
            robot.keyPress(keyCode);
            robot.delay(20);
            robot.keyRelease(keyCode);
            robot.delay(20);
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
        {
            pressUnicode(c, robot);
        }

    }
}
```

Basically when I got undefined keyCode for Robot I call pressUnicode function which is:

```
    static void pressUnicode(char c, Robot robot)
{
    String cantRecognize = ""+c;
    StringSelection selection = new StringSelection(cantRecognize);
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    clipboard.setContents(selection, null);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
}
```

Simply I'm just copying and pasting the character. This is working for all undefined characters. :)